# How to read blob data from sqlite and show it

Tags: java, android, sqlite, blob

I have downloaded a little sqlite database file with a few words and its definitions to learn making dictionaries. And its definitions are stored in blob type. How can I read it and show its definition. I do not know what exactly is stored in blob table. I tried these :

```
cursor = database.rawQuery("select body from items A inner join items_info B on A.id = B.id where B.id = '" + id + "';" , null);

        while (c.moveToNext()){
            byte[] blob = c.getBlob(0);
        }
```

And it got lots of various symbols with numbers and letters.
Then I converted it to string using

```
string = new String(blob, "UTF-8");
```

It gave me another result but not I want.

How can I get that blob data and show it?

Here is my db file

[image]

Comment: A `BLOB` is not a string. A `BLOB` is a binary object like an image. Do you know what kind of object `body` is?

Comment: I know that it is blob type else I know nothing about it

Comment: I need to get it cos the database I will use for my future dictionary app is also having blob type column

Comment: Maybe I can send you db file and you could open it tell me what is inside (size: is 34kb)

Comment: The only reason I can think of to store a word definition (Which sure sounds like it would be textual data) as a blob instead of text is if it's in some non-unicode character encoding and whoever made it didn't want to convert for some silly reason.

Comment: And how can I convert that value to normal String value?

Comment: Figure out what encoding is being used, and convert from that to a java string the usual way.

Comment: How can I figure out which encoding is used? Is there any tools for doing that

Answer (score 2):

try `SELECT hex(body) ....`
then you would get a hexadecimal String.

Comment: I tried and then converted it to string and then it gives me similar to this "ï¿½��������������ï¿½É´ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½Öï¿½ï¿½Ï´ï¿½I*ï¿½{ï¿½Ðï¿½Rï¿½paï¿½ï¿½&ï¿½ï¿½.ì»°GAï¿½b#ï¿½ï¿½uï¿½A!Q!YOï¿½ï¿½PSï¿½ï¿½&ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½/Nï¿½ï¿½4
    nï¿½ï¿½ ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½5ï¿½ï¿½��ï¿½ï¿½kï¿½c������"

Comment: did you used `c.getString(0)` ?

Comment: yeah I used getstring method

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem, a column that I stock it as an image and i tried to show it, then I found a tutorial my much help I recommend you to see this [tutorial](http://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-java/jdbc-read-write-blob/) how to write and read blob data.